# android map application error

Tags: android, dictionary

I'm doing a map application for the android phone but kept running into these errors when i run it.... can anyone help?? thank you!

Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".

and

Error Mon Apr 12 23:10:58 EDT 2010 Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/GoogleMaps/res/layout/main.xml'. org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/GoogleMaps/res/layout/main.xml'. at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.checkSynchronized(File.java:104)

My main file:

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you made a change of a file from outside eclipse.
Just hit F5 over the project or try a Project => Clean.